# Background image for button not working

Tags: css, asp.net

Hi I have a button in my form that triggers a pop up calendar for a date feild. I am trying to change the background image for the button with a calendar that I png image but cant get it to work

Here is the code

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_date" runat="server" Height="32px" Width="32px"
                                    CssClass="style60" Text="C" />
```

here is the css

```
.style60

        {

            background-image:url ("Pics/calendar.png");
            background-position: top;

        }
```

The size of the image is also 32x32 px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the ImageButton controller as per below sample:

```
<asp:ImageButton id="btn_date" runat="server"
           AlternateText="ImageButton 1"
           ImageAlign="left"
           ImageUrl="Pics/calendar.png"
           OnClick="ImageButton_Click"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try modifying the path of the image as shown below:

```
.style60

        {

            background-image:url ("./Pics/calendar.png");
            background-position: top;

        }
```

Comment: maybe you can use an ImageButton control. Which version of .net are you using?

Comment: Visual studio 2010 Professional.  How can i do that

Comment: then you should mark that answer as correct instead of this one ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try using an `ImageButton` instead of `Button`.

**Code**

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btn_date" runat="server" Height="32px" Width="32px"
                 ImageUrl="~/Pics/calendar.png" />
```